# How can I activate the pages machinery in GitHub without subdomains?

Tags: github

Is there any way to activate the Pages machinery in GitHub without going through the subdomains?  A practical case could be in a GitHub Enterprise instance.

Answer (score 2):

To view GitHub Pages (gh-pages branch) on your github enterprise server, use this URL structure:

```
http://[github-enterprise-domain]/pages/[username]/[repo]/
```

1. This URL structure doesn't work for github.com.
2. For user or organization pages, you can't create a "username.github.io" repo. Instead, you can create a repo and name it the same as your username or org, and then you use:

   /pages/[username]/[username]/

The 2nd [username] is simply the name of your repo.